# How to build project using MSBuild?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I need to build project B before building project A, using MSBuild.

I've tried to write `"D:\Visual Studio\IDE\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" $(SolutionDir)\FeedBack.App\FeedBack.App.csproj -property:Configuration=Debug` in project A prebuild command line, but I've got different errors before building it.

**Question**: What do I need to change in the command?

Comment: Did you try this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9736187/9071943

Comment: What are the errors? Are they compile errors?

Comment: @Ryan Thomas, yes, compile errors with exit codes. The last one, I remember, was 9009

Comment: @Phong, I've tried to do like in that topic, but I it didn't help, because, I don't exactly understand, how it works and what should be written there

Comment: can you build each project separately without error? Or face the same issue? Please check whether the path of the msbuild.exe and project path is correct. In addition, please share the error message or  A.csproj file. It will help us troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT, sorry for late answer. Both projects build well separately. I've tried write this command in different variants and got a lot of different results. Different exit codes: 3, 123, 9009, or message, that MSBuild.exe is not a command, sometimes another Visual Studio has been executed... I'm doing it in project A properties, in before-build events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that I haven't had the path to msbuild file as evironment variable in Windows properties.